# Weird Protobuf speedup by serializing list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, serialization, protobuf-net

I have found a very weird issue with ProtoBuf performance regarding serialization of large number of complex objects. Lets have these two scenarios :

A) Serialize a list of objects one by one

B) Serialize the list as a whole

By intuition, this should have similar performance. However, in my application, there 10x difference in deserialization just by putting the objects in the list and serializing the list.
Bellow you can find code to test this. The results vary in this example between 2x and 5x speedup, however in my code its prretty consistent 10x speedup.

**What is causing this ?** I have an app where I need to serialize objects one by one and its really downgrading performance, **is there any way to increase performance of one by one serialization** ?

Thanks

Output of code bellow

```
One by one serialization = 329204 ; deserialization = 41342
List serialization       = 19531 ; deserialization = 27716
```

Code

```
[ProtoContract]
    class TestObject
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]public string str1;
        [ProtoMember(2)]public string str2;
        [ProtoMember(3)]public int i1;
        [ProtoMember(4)]public int i2;
        [ProtoMember(5)]public double d1;
        [ProtoMember(6)]public double d2;
        public TestObject(int cnt)
        {
            str1 = $"Hello World {cnt}";
            str2 = $"Lorem ipsum {cnt}";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) str1 = str1 + str1;
            d1 = i1 = cnt;
            d2 = i2 = cnt * 2;
        }
        public TestObject() { }
    }
    private void ProtoBufTest()
    {
        //init test data
        List<TestObject> objects = new List<TestObject>();
        int numObjects = 1000;
        for(int i = 0; i < numObjects;i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new TestObject(i));
        }
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        //test 1 
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix<TestObject>(memStream, objects[i], ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }
        long timeToSerializeSeparately = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        memStream.Position = 0;

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TestObject>(memStream, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }
        long timeToDeserializeSeparately = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        //test 2
        memStream.Position = 0;
        sw.Restart();
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix<List<TestObject>>(memStream, objects, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128);
        long timeToSerializeList = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        memStream.Position = 0;
        sw.Restart();
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<List<TestObject>>(memStream,  ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128);
        long timeToDeserializeList = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine($"One by one serialization = {timeToSerializeSeparately} ; deserialization = {timeToDeserializeSeparately}");
        Console.WriteLine($"List serialization       = {timeToSerializeList} ; deserialization = {timeToDeserializeList}");
    }
```

Comment: @Sinatr is there some way to force ProtoBuf to cache reflection data between calls ? That would help a lot probably

Comment: @Sinatr actually, that is a complete misunderstanding of what this code is showing, and just about everything you said is simply factually wrong (100% wrong, inverted in fact). There is no "obviously" when it comes to complex code and performance. The actual thing being shown in this test is the per-type reflection cost and the JIT cost, both of which only happen once, and that cost is being incorrectly attributed to the single object serialization. protobuf-net is actually **faster** with single root objects than root lists. Serializing root collections is actively harmful here.

Comment: @Sinatr as an extension: a cheeky way to *speed up* serializing a root collection is to define a single root object that *has* a list as the only member, and move from `Serialize(list)` to `Serialize(new ListWrapper { Items = list; })`
; seriously. That allows the meta-programming layer to optimize for the specific list type during IL emit, rather than relying on `IEnumerable` etc. This also allows custom iterators to be used when they are defined (like they are for `List<T>` etc), and allows for array optimization, etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I was trying to explain test results without checking the test code itself (which is poor, as there is no *warning up* or repeating the test). Blaming reflection was bad idea, I can imagine if someone would say something bad about what I had optimized at first, sorry. Obviously (again this word) that would be the first thing to optimize by using some kind of dictionary/cache.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misrepresenting the initial reflection pre-processing and the JIT costs; if we change it so it runs the test multiple times:

```
static void Main()
{
    ProtoBufTest(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ProtoBufTest(1000);
    }
}

private static void ProtoBufTest(int numObjects)
{
    ...
```

then I the results I would expect, where the single object code is **faster**.

Basically, it does a **lot** of work the first time it is needed, essentially exactly what you ask here:

> is there some way to force ProtoBuf to cache reflection data between calls ? That would help a lot probably

already happens. As a side note, you can also do:

```
    Serializer.PrepareSerializer<TestObject>();
```

once right at the start of your app, and it will do as much as possible then. I can't force JIT to happen, though - to do that, you need to invoke the code once.